# Estimating a single model changing multiple variables

Tags: r, plm

I have a panel dataset and I am trying to estimate multiple models using different key independent variables. 
My dataset looks something like this

```
df <- data.frame(y = rnorm(9),id= c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), time=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), x1 = rnorm(9), x2 = rnorm(9), x3 = rnorm(9), c1 = rnorm(9),  c2 = rnorm(9))

df <- pdata.frame(df, index=c("id","time"))
```

Where *y* is the key dependent variable, *id* is the unit identifier and *time* is the time identifier. *c1 and c2* are controls, and *x1,x2,x3* are key independent variables of interest. 
I know that I can estimate these model separately like this:

```
library(plm)
m1<- plm(y ~  lag(x1, k = 1)+ lag(y,k=1) + lag(c1, k = 1) + 
  lag(c2, k = 1), data = df, effect = "twoways", 
model = "within")

m2<- plm(y ~  lag(x2, k = 1)+ lag(y,k=1) + lag(c1, k = 1) + 
  lag(c2, k = 1), data = df, effect = "twoways", 
model = "within")
```

And so on...

However, I was looking for a more concise way to write and examine different models since I have 16 independent variables of interest and multiple dependent variables to examine. 
I would like to:

1) Find a way to "group" all of the independent variables. So that I can write the model only once (the controls and dv remain the same) and r computes all of the models for each independent variable.

2) Ideally, the command should also immediately display all of the results in an orderly fashion (stargazer?), so that I can quickly examine which model performs better and which one performs worse.

Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: I've done something like this in the past with a modular approach where I 1) make a list of the model formulas I want to try; 2) write a function to perform all desired operations on a generic model; and then 3) use `lapply` to apply the function from step 2 to each of the models in the list created in step 1. One nice feature of this approach is that you can efficiently tweak your model summarization operations by changing your function (or adding others) and quickly re-running them.

Comment: It sounds like what I am looking for, but would you be able to provide me with one simple example that goes through each of the steps so that I can tweak it for my needs? I am not sure I am able to write the syntax you are describing otherwise

Comment: No, sorry, that's too much work for me.